# Which episode is this eye in hand from and what is its purpose?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

I was listening to some cover of Cruel's Angel Thesis when I stumbled upon this image:

[image: Screenshot of youtube video with strange image]

Since every other image used in the video does come from NGE/EoE, I am inclined to think it does come from an episode of Evangelion.

However, I don't recognize the scene, and don't know of any character with such a... scar, nor its use.

Does anyone remember where it appears? What is it and what is its purpose?

Comment: It was added when they redid the series the first time. Adam was kept in a brief case in the original series, but in the slightly altered version Gendo has Adam implanted in his hand for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is Gendo Ikari's hand with the first angel [Adam](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Adam) implanted on it. From the linked article:

> Adam is a crucial element in Gendo's own scenario for Third Impact, wherein he intends to use the "forbidden fusion of Adam and Lilith" as a means to achieve reunion with Yui. At an undisclosed point, Gendo has Adam fused into his right palm, and, in the moments before Third Impact, he inserts his hand into Rei. However, rather than carry out his wishes, Rei severs and absorbs Gendo's arm — fusing with Adam, but rejecting Gendo. The "forbidden fusion" is complete when Rei returns to Lilith.

The screenshot is from episode 24.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the use Gendo had to implant Adam in his hand? (I presume it's related to EoE, but I don't remeber using that at any moment)

Comment: Gendo does something unmentionable to Rei via that hand that holds the embryonic form of Adam, let's just leave it at that.